# How to write Data into Database using SQlite?

Tags: iphone, sql, sqlite

I had used this code to write enteries into database but it is no refelecting into it...I don't know why?? Please give your suggestions!!Thanks in advance..

```
NSString* user_Name=txt_UserName.text;
NSString* password=txt_Password.text;
NSString* rePassword=txt_RePassword.text;
if ([password isEqualToString:rePassword]) {

sqlite3 *database;
sqlite3_stmt *compiledQuery;
// Open the database from the users filessytem
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
    const char *sqlStatement = "insert into Main values(?,?)";
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledQuery, NULL);
    sqlite3_bind_text(compiledQuery, 1, [user_Name UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(compiledQuery, 2, [password UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);       
    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(compiledQuery))
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledQuery);
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Comment: Have you debug this? is it coming inside if loop?

Comment: Please use CoreData. More powerfull and more friendly to use. See: http://developer.apple.com/cocoa/coredatatutorial/index.html

Answer (score 0):

is the path to the database is correct ? You can check the database path by

```
NSString *documentsDir = [DbCls getPath];
NSString *databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:DBNAME];

+(NSString *) getPath
{
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    return documentsDir;
}
```

Comment: I had checked it...Path to database is correct!! because i'm also reading data from it...which is working fine....Thanks for showing your interest!!

Comment: I'm not getting any error.It is running fine.But after doing "Insert" command it is not reflecting into database.